# runing an QApplication in a shared library (without main) on ubuntu using QT

Tags: c++, qt

I need to write a shared library (which connects a static library to a software). The static library is a QWizardPage based project which is designed to make an future Interface while the software is running.

The static Library:
.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-09-29T01:12:06
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += widgets

TARGET = FutureInterface
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

SOURCES += futureinterface.cpp

HEADERS += futureinterface.h
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}

FORMS += \
    futureinterface.ui
```

.h

```
#ifndef FUTUREINTERFACE_H
#define FUTUREINTERFACE_H

#include <QWizardPage>

namespace Ui {
    class FutureInterface;
}

class FutureInterface : public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FutureInterface(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FutureInterface();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::FutureInterface *ui;
};

#endif // FUTUREINTERFACE_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "futureinterface.h"
#include "ui_futureinterface.h"

FutureInterface::FutureInterface(QWidget *parent) :
    QWizardPage(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FutureInterface)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

FutureInterface::~FutureInterface()
{
    delete ui;
}

void FutureInterface::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}
```

I need to run FutureInterface in my shared library in the following function.

---

The whole code of the shared library:

```
#include "v_repExtQuadRotor.h"
#include "scriptFunctionData.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "v_repLib.h"
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include "FutureInterface/futureinterface.h"
#include <QApplication>

typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 7, 1> vector7f;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 6, 1> vector6f;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> vector4f;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 6, 6> matrix66f;

#ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef QT_COMPIL
        #include <direct.h>
    #else
        #include <shlwapi.h>
        #pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
    #endif
#endif /* _WIN32 */
#if defined (__linux) || defined (__APPLE__)
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define WIN_AFX_MANAGE_STATE
#endif /* __linux || __APPLE__ */

#define CONCAT(x,y,z) x y z
#define strConCat(x,y,z)    CONCAT(x,y,z)

#define PLUGIN_NAME "QuadRotor"

LIBRARY vrepLib;

struct sQuadRotor
{
    int motorHandles[4];
    vector4f jointVelocity;
    vector6f sensorData;
};
std::vector<sQuadRotor> allQuadRotors;
void app(){
    int argc = 1;
    char appname[] = "App";
    char* argv[] = {appname, NULL};
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FutureInterface w;
    w.show();
    int i=a.exec();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// simExtQuadRotor_create
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define LUA_CREATE_QRCOMMAND "simExtQuadRotor_create"

const int inArgs_QRCREATE[]={

    1,
    sim_script_arg_int32|sim_script_arg_table,4,
};

void LUA_CREATE_QRCALLBACK(SScriptCallBack* cb)
{
    allQuadRotors.clear();
    CScriptFunctionData D;
    if (D.readDataFromStack(cb->stackID,inArgs_QRCREATE,inArgs_QRCREATE[0],LUA_CREATE_QRCOMMAND))
    {
        std::vector<CScriptFunctionDataItem>* inData=D.getInDataPtr();
        sQuadRotor QuadRotor;
        for(int n=0;n<4;n++){
            QuadRotor.motorHandles[n]=inData->at(0).int32Data[n];
        }
        QuadRotor.jointVelocity<<Eigen::VectorXf::Zero(4);
        QuadRotor.sensorData<<Eigen::VectorXf::Zero(6);
        allQuadRotors.push_back(QuadRotor);
    }
    D.pushOutData(CScriptFunctionDataItem(1));
    D.writeDataToStack(cb->stackID);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



VREP_DLLEXPORT unsigned char v_repStart(void* reservedPointer,int reservedInt)
{ // This is called just once, at the start of V-REP.
    // Dynamically load and bind V-REP functions:
    char curDirAndFile[1024];
#ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef QT_COMPIL
        _getcwd(curDirAndFile, sizeof(curDirAndFile));
    #else
        GetModuleFileName(NULL,curDirAndFile,1023);
        PathRemoveFileSpec(curDirAndFile);
    #endif
#elif defined (__linux) || defined (__APPLE__)
    getcwd(curDirAndFile, sizeof(curDirAndFile));
#endif
    std::string currentDirAndPath(curDirAndFile);
    std::string temp(currentDirAndPath);

#ifdef _WIN32
    temp+="\\v_rep.dll";
#elif defined (__linux)
    temp+="/libv_rep.so";
#elif defined (__APPLE__)
    temp+="/libv_rep.dylib";
#endif /* __linux || __APPLE__ */

    vrepLib=loadVrepLibrary(temp.c_str());
    if (vrepLib==NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error, could not find or correctly load v_rep.dll. Cannot start 'QuadRotor' plugin.\n";
        return(0); // Means error, V-REP will unload this plugin
    }
    if (getVrepProcAddresses(vrepLib)==0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error, could not find all required functions in v_rep.dll. Cannot start 'QuadRotor' plugin.\n";
        unloadVrepLibrary(vrepLib);
        return(0); // Means error, V-REP will unload this plugin
    }

    // Check the V-REP version:
    int vrepVer;
    simGetIntegerParameter(sim_intparam_program_version,&vrepVer);
    if (vrepVer<30200) // if V-REP version is smaller than 3.02.00
    {
        std::cout << "Sorry, your V-REP copy is somewhat old, V-REP 3.2.0 or higher is required. Cannot start 'QuadRotor' plugin.\n";
        unloadVrepLibrary(vrepLib);
        return(0); // Means error, V-REP will unload this plugin
    }

    // Register 4 new Lua commands:
    simRegisterScriptCallbackFunction(strConCat(LUA_CREATE_QRCOMMAND,"@",PLUGIN_NAME),strConCat("number QuadRotorHandle=",LUA_CREATE_QRCOMMAND,"(table_4 JointHandles)"),LUA_CREATE_QRCALLBACK);

    return(8); // initialization went fine, we return the version number of this plugin (can be queried with simGetModuleName)
    // version 1 was for V-REP versions before V-REP 2.5.12
    // version 2 was for V-REP versions before V-REP 2.6.0
    // version 5 was for V-REP versions before V-REP 3.1.0 
    // version 6 is for V-REP versions after V-REP 3.1.3
    // version 7 is for V-REP versions after V-REP 3.2.0 (completely rewritten)
    // version 8 is for V-REP versions after V-REP 3.3.0 (using stacks for data exchange with scripts)
}

VREP_DLLEXPORT void v_repEnd()
{ // This is called just once, at the end of V-REP
    unloadVrepLibrary(vrepLib); // release the library
}

VREP_DLLEXPORT void* v_repMessage(int message,int* auxiliaryData,void* customData,int* replyData)
{ // This is called quite often. Just watch out for messages/events you want to handle
    // This function should not generate any error messages:
    int errorModeSaved;
    simGetIntegerParameter(sim_intparam_error_report_mode,&errorModeSaved);
    simSetIntegerParameter(sim_intparam_error_report_mode,sim_api_errormessage_ignore);
    void* retVal=NULL;
    if (message==sim_message_eventcallback_modulehandle)
    {
        if ( (customData==NULL)||(std::string("QuadRotor").compare((char*)customData)==0) ) // is the command also meant for QuadRotor?
        {
          if(allQuadRotors.size()>0){
              //controller***********************************************************************************
              app();

          }
        }
    }

    if (message==sim_message_eventcallback_simulationended)
    { // simulation ended. Destroy all QuadRotor instances:
        allQuadRotors.clear();
    }

    simSetIntegerParameter(sim_intparam_error_report_mode,errorModeSaved); // restore previous settings
    return(retVal);
}
```

Do I need to install some packages or some dependencies? Because, now my software would not be able to load shared library. it seems that the software is not be able to find the QWizardPage dependencies. Could you tell me what I mess? Thanks a lot

It seems that the software could not load it because I used QApplication to execute static library in the shared library?

using QApplication in the shared library is wrong? Should I do some thing else?

Comment: Try to add `#include <QApplication>` line in the file with `v_repMessage` functions

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem, I build shared library perfectly.

Comment: Do I need to install some packages or some dependencies. Because, now my software would not be able to load shared library. it seems that the software is not be able to find the  QWizardPage dependencies. Could you tell me what I mess? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of the version of QT. The Software was implemented in a different QT version, in contrast to the version that I tried to implement my code in.